# Model object not creating from inside except block or right before raising exception

Tags: django, django-models

Something very strange is happening in my Django app. When I try to run the following code

```
Model.objects.create(**obj)
```

before raising an exception OR run the same code inside an except block, the code runs without any issue, but I cannot see the object in the database. Running the Model.objects.all() also doesn't return anything.

This is the complete code:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            serializer = VerifyOTPRequestSerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            otp = request.data.pop("otp")
            flow = request.data.pop("flow")
            primary_phone = request.data.get("contact_detail", {}).get(
                "primary_phone", ""
            )            
            if OTPFailedAttempts.objects.filter(phone=primary_phone).count() > 0:
                raise Exception("otpAttemptError")
            
            return helpers.OTPHelper.verify_otp(primary_phone, otp, flow)
        except Exception as permission_error:
            
            OTPFailedAttempts.objects.create(**{"phone": primary_phone, 'email': email})

            return False
```

As requested in the comments, the setting for `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` is as follows:

```
ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True
```

Is there a particular reason why Django doesn't allow object creation of objects around exceptions or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does it really ever reach `except` block? Because it sounds that it does not. Print yourself something just after that `create()` method, and you will see if it is actually reached.

Comment: @NixonSparrow yes it does. I have added print and I also saved the return value of the create command in an object. It even has an ID but somehow the object is deleted after insertion.

Comment: Maybe you set [ATOMIC_REQUESTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests) to `True` or use the `trasaction.atomic` decorator and this rolls back your changes due to some other uncaught exception?

Comment: Yes, the ATOMIC_REQUESTS is set to True, but I don't see how that can make an effect here. The code runs completely fine. The only reason I can think of is that it gets rolled back due to being inserted inside an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your requests are atomic since you have set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` to `True` in your settings.

Django Rest Framework has a method `check_permissions` which calls the `has_permission` method of all the permission classes of a view,if **any** of these return `False` (or a falsy value) then an exception is raised (Reference: [GitHub code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f4cf0260bf3c9323e798325702be690ca25949ca/rest_framework/views.py#L169-L175)).

Since your `has_permission` method returns `False` this raises an exception. Given that you have set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True` (Django Rest Framework has code to comply with this setting) this causes your changes to be rolled back. The solution would be to remove `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` and handle it yourself using the decorator / context manager provided by Django.